# What is Boolean [ ] ba[ ] supposed to mean?

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

what is `Boolean [] ba[]` supposed to mean? Is it an array (with name ba) of boolean type of an array of an array?

Comment: Can you show it in context? As in a complete, syntactically correct line which uses it?

Comment: Apply the same concept of that question: write `Boolean[] ba[]` as `Boolean[][] ba` and check for yourself.